# Error Missing \endcsname inserted in algpseudocode package LaTex

Tags: latex, overleaf

i'm trying to write algorithm with algpseudocode package in LaTex end got error
"Missing \endcsname inserted". What's wrong with my code..?

When i compile it, it compiled well and looks good in the paper, but still error in the code.

Here are the code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[hbt!]
\caption{ Grain 128 AEAD Decrypt with NIST API}\label{alg:cap}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output}}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require {ad, adlen, m, mlen, k, nonce}
\Ensure {m}
\State {Initialize generator with k and nonce}
\State Construct $c'= (Encode(adlen)||ad||c_0,....c_{clen-65}||0x80)$
\State {Let}
\State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $M$ = bit length of $Encode(adlen)||ad$
\State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $mlen = clen - 64$
\State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $d_i = 0,$ $(0 \leq i \leq M-1)$
\State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} $d_i = 1,$ $(M \leq i \leq M+mlen-1)$
\State {$Decrypt$ using $m'_i = c'_i \oplus z_{i}d_{i}, (0 \leq i \leq M+mlen-1)$}
\State {$Authenticate$ using $z'_i$ and generate $A_{M+mlen+1}$}
\State Set $m = m'_{M+mlen-1}$
\If {$c_{clen-64},......c_{clen-1} == A_{M+mlen+1}$}
\State return 0
\Else
\State return -1
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Here the output look:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyUgN.png)

What's wrong..?

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question including a class and the necessary packages to compile your code.